# The tagging system appears to be broken

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tagging

With many thanks to [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/september-2016-tag-rename-synonym-megaquestion) a lot of tags have recently been renamed or synonymised. These include, for example, renaming [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) to [drones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) and [ecuador-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador-citizens) to [ecuadorian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuadorian-citizens).

However, although it seems renaming can have retrospective effect this question:

[Is it legal to bring a drone to Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81067/is-it-legal-to-bring-a-drone-to-japan)

is still tagged [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) (a tag added by @[Ali Awan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/81067/2) on October 20, 2016) though the renaming appears to have taken place after December 18, 2016 (and by December 22, 2016).

Also this question:

[Ecuadorian traveling to Sochi via Heathrow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35736/ecuadorian-traveling-to-sochi-via-heathrow)

was still tagged [ecuador-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador-citizens) – but this has just changed to [ecuadorian-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuadorian-citizens).

Searching for questions tagged [drones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) returns no results (nor any tagged [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone). Searching for questions tagged [ecuador-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecuador-citizens) (now) returns the above question, but only the above question – until "edit tags" and "Save Tag Edits".

"edit tags" and "Save Tag Edits" seems all that is required to update the display of the tag name, though apparently rather futile without any other change whatever and, it seems, this bumps the questions which is very much not appreciated by [some users](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/excessive-editing-of-old-posts).

How can I add either [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) or [drones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) say to [Can I import a drone into Argentina?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71546/can-i-import-a-drone-into-argentina) or find questions tagged [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) by the tagging system and, having found them, change [drone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) to [drones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) given that attempts to do so are met with a pop up stating:

> You are attempting to create the tag [drones]; however the tag [drones] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

?

Comment: @jmac Any chance that someone could have a look at that?

Comment: The behaviour is indeed really weird. Whenever I edit a question that is tagged [drone] or [standard-visitor-visa] it changes the tag automatically to the plural form without me doing anything. In the timeline of the question however it looks like I changed the tags.

Comment: Yes, but the tags were not changed when I renamed the tags, but today, weeks later, when I edited a random part of the question.